# $U$ $\setminus$ $K$ is an open connected set

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $U$ be an open connected subset of $\Bbb{C}$ and $K$ $\subset$ $U$ a closed ball around $p \in U$. Show that $U\setminus K$is an open connected set.

I probably have to prove it by contradiction but I don‘t know how.

Comment: Are you assuming that $U$ is in a metric space? (as you used the term _closed ball_)

Comment: $U=(-1,1)$, $p=0$ and $K=[-1/2,1/2]$.  $U\setminus K$ is not connected.

Comment: If you want it to be connected than you need to put some additional constraints on $K$, if you just want it open then it is simply due to the fact that $U-K = U \cap K^c$ which is the intersection of two open sets and hence open.

Answer (score 3):

As $K$ is closed, $U\setminus K$ is open. It remains to show that $U\setminus K$ is connected.

Wlog. $K=\overline{B_1(0)}$ is the closed unit disk and wlog. $U\subseteq B_2(0)$.
The function $K\to (0,1]$, $x\mapsto d(x,\Bbb C\setminus U)$ is continuous on the compact $\partial K$, hence assumes its minimum $m>0$.
Then for all $\rho$ with $1<\rho<1+m$, it follows that $\rho S^1\subset U$.
Note that for open sets in $\Bbb C$, connected implies path-connected.
Let $a,b\in U\setminus K$. Then there exists a path $\gamma$ in $U$ from $a$ to $b$. If that path avoids $K$, we are done. And if the path passes through $K$, pick $\rho$ with $1<\rho<\min\{|a|,|b|\}$. Then $\gamma$ will have a first and a last intersection with $\rho S^1$. Replace the part between these to points with an arc of $\rho S^1$ to obtain a path from $a$ to $b$ in $U\setminus K$.